# Applying width to flex item, same value as flex-basis, causes spacing changes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I noticed some strange behavior in a web project of mine. I've recreated similar behavior in a codepen to demonstrate:

The summary is:

- I have a flex item specified as: `flex: 0 0 170px;`
- Devtools shows its computed value as 170px (as expected).
- If I add an additional css property of "width: 170px", some spacing of other elements in the dom changes.

I would expect setting this property to have no effect, but that's not the case.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/BaPKRQd

Edit: Here's a simplified codepen: https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/eYjZEve (I found I could remove some of the size styling CSS, and still repro the problem)

This image shows that we're dealing with a computed width of 170px for the div in question (with an X)
[image: Image showing computed tab]

This shows that, before I set the width property on that div, we see spacing as shown.
[image: Image before setting width property]

After I set the width property for that div (to the same width as the flex-basis, and to the same value as was computed), some spacing overall in the dom shrinks.
[image: Image after setting width property]

Very curious for any thoughts on why this is having any effect at all. Thank you.

Edit: For refernce, this repros on Chrome Version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 11. Not sure about other environments.

Comment: Same issue on firefox dev edition. Css tricks states "[flex-basis] specifies the initial size of the flex item, before any available space is distributed according to the flex factors." ... mdn states "[flex-basis] sets the size of the content box unless otherwise set with box-sizing" ... I tried removing padding/border/margin. I tried setting the box-sizing. I'm confused lol. I have a feeling it is something to do with that "initial size ... before space is distributed" portion ... something about the order of calculations? But I really don't know. Interesting though.

Comment: `#rightContainer` takes up its full `max-width: 320px` and consumes an additional `margin: 2%` from `#outerFlex`, leaving `700px - 326.4 = 373.6px` minus a few `border` = `364px` for `#nestedFlex` to distribute two columns of `170px` with `space-evenly`. `364px - 2 * 170px - 4 * 1px border = 20px` to create even spacing around the items, divided by 3 ~ `7px` of space between and outside the items. Without the `.rightPosObj`  child element `#rightContainer` will only take up its `min-width: 300px` giving the container `20px` more to space evenly. From the top of my head, I think ;-)

Comment: Oh, `flex-basis` supercedes `width`, MDN says...

Answer (score 0):

Writing my comment as an anwser for clearer text:

- `#rightContainer` with a `170px` child element takes up its full max-width: 320px
- and consumes an additional `margin: 2%` from `#outerFlex`

This leaves `700px - 326.4 = 373.6px` minus a few border = `364px` for `#nestedFlex` to distribute two columns of `170px` with space-evenly.

- `364px - 2 * 170px - 4 * 1px border = 20px` to create even spacing around the child elements.
- divided by 3  = `~7px` of space between and outside the child elements.

Without the `.rightPosObj` (either `.rightPosObj` disabled or the entire `<div class="rightPosObj">` removed) child element `#rightContainer` will only take up its `min-width: 300px` giving `#rightContainer` `20px` additional pixels to space evenly. Basically `(20px + 20px) / 3 = ~13px` between and outside the child elements.

Hense the tiny shift in spacing...

Comment: When you say "Without the .rightPosObj child element", can you clarify what you mean? I do see the same shfit when I remove that element from the dom, but to repro this, I'm setting the 'width' property, to the same value as it is currently calculated.

Comment: You said *If I add an additional css property of "width: 170px", some spacing of other elements in the dom changes.*. Therefore I removed it again to see the difference.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following. What are you removing? The element from the dom? Or, the 'width' property? And if it's the 'width' property, can you help me to understand why it's having any effect at all given that the computed size is the same?

Comment: Both. I tested two cases: 1) with disabled `.rightPosObj` and 2) with removed `<div class="positionedObj rightPosObj">Toggle my width</div>` to see the different space distributions. In both cases `#rightContainer` varies in width between `300px` and `320px` causing the difference in `space-evenly` pixel usage. With `.rightPosObj` enabled (or present) forces `#rightContainer` to grow, making `#leftContainer` shrink, leaving less space to evenly distribute.

Comment: >With .rightPosObj enabled (or present) forces #rightContainer to grow
But the width of .rightPosObject is already 170px before (or after) the .rightPosObject class sets it explicitly, right? So why does toggling .rightPosObject have this effect? What is the reason for #rightContainer to change? I don't mean to go in circles, but this is the peace I'm missing.

Comment: No worries, circles are the best to run in, you never get lost. Maybe either of us sees something the other doesn't. I'll give it another go...